# Boot custom Linux image using PXE

Tags: ubuntu, pxe, tftpd

Is it possible to boot a client over PXE using custom Linux image using PXELINUX?

**Background**

> We use various IoT devices (Intel based processor) that use Linux as OS (Ubuntu to be
>   specific). But we have customized OS based on our need (for example by
>   adding our own applications, system configuration etc). Now, we are
>   looking into possibility if we can boot off these devices using PXE as
>   a fail-safe for local storage corruption (or just get away from that).
>
> I am able to achieve this using standard Ubuntu images using TFTPD64
>   (on Windows) and PXELINUX. And I can selectively boot image for
>   different devices based on their MAC IDs. But I am having hard time
>   make it work for our image.

So my question is, how can I create custom image (or use any other mean) to boot our Linux system using PXE?

I created ISO using DD utility (over 4GB in size). But PXELINUX bootloader fails to even download that ISO.

Comment: PXE support in ARM is not a given....

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned, its not ARM processor. Device that I want to use on has Intel processor. Updating my question to reflect that.

Comment: A pxe loader wont book an ISO, it needs to boot a kernel.

Comment: @JackLock I've posted answer with general steps to do what you want. If you want more specific info, then provide more info about doing following (in my answer) steps. I did PXE with custom images 2 month ago. Also you can see my post for snapshots capability over overlayfs on PXE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420646/mount-root-as-overlayfs/421466#421466

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I can access to whole file system so I can access kernel (vmlinuz) too. But what I don't understand is how to make it work. I am venturing into bit unknown territory so don't mind my unfamiliarity with terms.

Answer (score 2):

These steps helps to you boot your custom image:

1) You need decide location of your future **root (/)** (is being located entirely in network resource (i.e. **NFS**) or it will be loaded into RAM during the boot.

2) Prepare your **initrd** depends on step 1).

3) Place your **kernel** and **initrd** in **TFTP** server.

4) Change your `/etc/fstab` of your system image (it may be iso or **squashfs** or entirely unpacked on network resource).

---

Result boot sequence:

1) Kernel unpack initrd and pass control to it.

2) Initrd mount network resource (or copy to RAM (**tmpfs**) if loaded system will be entirely located in RAM).

3) Initrd return control to kernel and kernel loads `init/systemd` from mounted prepared **root (/).**

Comment: I am using Windows as my PXE server. So I am going to use "cifs" instead of NFS. And it really doesn't matter if we keep it on network or in memory. Question is, how do I edit my initrd file? And what is expected there?

Comment: @JackLock Lets discuss this in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75426/pxe-cifs